# Oracle AWR to CSV converter?

Tags: oracle, csv, awr

Is there any converter available that help me convert all tables in my AWR report into CSV?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/133693). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Answer (score 1):

[The AWR formatter extension](http://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/awr-formatter-1-6-released/) for Google Chrome has a handy table to CSV export function,  and lots of other AWR formatting goodies.

Answer (score 0):

AWR report is combination lot link. It is very difficult to read in CSV file. so open in html file so reading will easy.